# Is this function in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^3)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

It seems such a trivial question, but for whatever reason I don't understand.

Let $u: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R $ be $$u(x) = \frac 1{4\pi |x|}$$

The book says that $u \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^3)$ which I don't understand,because in a compact subset containing $0$ that function is not inegrable!

$u(x) = \frac 1{4\pi\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}}$ and if for example $x_2 = x_3 = 0$ and our function is $\sim \frac 1{|x_1|}$ which is not integrable..

Comment: But $\{ x : x_2 = x_3 = 0\}$ is a null set. If you write things in spherical coordinates, you see that you basically have a $$\int_0^R \frac{1}{4\pi r}\cdot r^2\,dr,$$ and that gives you a finite integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh dear.. You are right thank you! Go ahead and make that an answer if you want! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we transform it into spherical coordinates on a ball centred at $0$, the determinant of the change of variables gives us a factor of $r^2$ which (more than) cancels the singularity at $0$ as far as integration is concerned,

$$\int_{\lvert x\rvert < R} \frac{1}{4\pi\,\lvert x\rvert}\,d\lambda = \int_0^R\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{4\pi r}\cdot r^2\sin\vartheta\,d\vartheta\,d\varphi\,dr = \int_0^R r\,dr = \frac{R^2}{2} < +\infty,$$

so we see that $u$ is integrable on all balls centred at $0$ with finite radius. Since every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is contained in such a ball, we see that $u\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again! :)